# Android Build Error - Ubuntu & TaintDroid

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Attempting to use Android in Ubuntu to study TaintDroid and running into some issues. I followed the instructions at  http://appanalysis.org/download_2.3.html

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit in Virtual box

When I get to Make, i get the following stacktrace

```
colin@colin-VirtualBox:~/tdroid/tdroid-2.3.4_r1$ ls
bionic    cts          device      hardware  ndk       prebuilt
bootable  dalvik       external    libcore   out       sdk
build     development  frameworks  Makefile  packages  system   
colin@colin-VirtualBox:~/tdroid/tdroid-2.3.4_r1$ . build/envsetup.sh     
including device/htc/passion/vendorsetup.sh   
including device/samsung/crespo/vendorsetup.sh
colin@colin-VirtualBox:~/tdroid/tdroid-2.3.4_r1$ lunch 1

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.4
TARGET_PRODUCT=generic
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=false
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=GRJ22
============================================
colin@colin-VirtualBox:~/tdroid/tdroid-2.3.4_r1$ make -j4
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.4
TARGET_PRODUCT=generic
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=false
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=GRJ22
============================================
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
find: `frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html': No such file or directory
find: `out/target/common/docs/gen': No such file or directory
host Java: apicheck (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/apicheck_intermediates/classes)
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libexpat/expat_external.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libexpat/expat.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libexpat/expat.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libexpat/expat_external.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libpng/pngconf.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libpng/png.h
Header: out/host/linux-x86/obj/include/libpng/pngusr.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libpng/png.h    
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libpng/pngusr.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libpng/pngconf.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libwpa_client/wpa_ctrl.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/eas.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/eas_types.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/eas_reverb.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/jet.h
Header: out/target/product/generic/obj/include/libsonivox/ARM_synth_constants_gnu.inc
host Java: clearsilver (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/clearsilver_intermediates  /classes)
target Java: core (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/classes)
host Java: dx (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/dx_intermediates/classes)
Notice file: frameworks/base/libs/utils/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/libutils.a.txt
Notice file: system/core/liblog/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/liblog.a.txt
Notice file: system/core/libcutils/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/libcutils.a.txt
Notice file: external/expat/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/libexpat.a.txt
Notice file: external/libpng/NOTICE -- out/host/linux-x86/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//lib/libpng.a.txt
Yacc: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
bison -d  -o out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
touch out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.hpp
echo '#ifndef 'aidl_language_y_h > out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.h
echo '#define 'aidl_language_y_h >> out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.h
cat out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.hpp >> out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.h
 echo '#endif' >> out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.h
rm -f out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.hpp   
 Lex: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.l
 /bin/bash: flex: command not found
  make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp] Error 127 
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.    
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
colin@colin-VirtualBox:~/tdroid/tdroid-2.3.4_r1$ emulator
emulator: command not found
```

Has anyone had a similar issue? Linux and the terminal are somewhat foreign to me.

Comment: What happens if you just read the error messages? No such file or directory means just that -- so go create it.

Answer (score 0):

You may miss some required packages.

Try `$ sudo apt-get install flex` before `$ make -j4`